# Maximizing this binomial PMF?

Tags: probability

I have the question from an college exam last year

> Assume that we observe a new, young player doing free throws. We do
> not know his success probability θ. Let Y denote the number of
> successes and denote the pmf by pY,θ. We observe that out of 20
> attempts, he succeeds 17 times. Write down pY,θ(17) and maximize with
> respect to θ. The result you get is the value of θ that makes the
> observed data most likely.

Then the solution is given as

[image]

(No idea why they made the text gray-ish)

So yes, I get the formula for $p_{Y, \theta}$ but why do you need to find the derivative of this function to maximize it? Here is the graph for the PMF:

[image]

From this graph, I only get more confused: To function is only growing, so there is no maximum, right? If the x($\theta$) should be within 0 and 1, wouldn't the maximum simply always be at x=1? Also, the solution set finds the derivative of the PMF and this gives the maximum of $\theta$ for some reason but looking at the slope of this graph, no maxima seem to take place at $\theta = \frac{17}{20}$

Comment: did you plot this all the way to $x=1$ for $x^{17}(1-x)^3$? Since I plotted it and get a clear maximum. (see [this](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB841GB841&ei=APCoXfmeDIn4wQLzl5_YCQ&q=%28x%5E17%29%281-x%29%5E3&oq=%28x%5E17%29%281-x%29%5E3&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30l10.10529.12646..12953...0.2..0.67.133.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.Td0HtbRRm_Q&ved=0ahUKEwj5nvzAsKTlAhUJfFAKHfPLB5sQ4dUDCAs&uact=5))

Comment: @Chinny84 I just hate when this happens. You got it right - thank you so much!! Much appreciated

Comment: no problem :) at all.